# Django, extract kwargs from url

Tags: django

Suppose I have a url pattern

```
url(r'^/my_app/class/(?P<class_id>\d+)/$', my_class.my_class, name='my_class')
```

For a given url

`http://example.com/my_app/class/3/`, I'd like to get `class_id`. 
I can do this with regex myself.
I am wondering if there's a utility function for this since Django is already doing this to resolve url to a view.

Comment: how about django.urls.resolve() https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example of using `resolve()` function in Django docs. Value of `next` variable has HTTP url to be parsed with `urlparse()` / `resolve()`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve

```
from django.urls import resolve
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.utils.six.moves.urllib.parse import urlparse

def myview(request):
    next = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', None) or '/'
    response = HttpResponseRedirect(next)

    # modify the request and response as required, e.g. change locale
    # and set corresponding locale cookie

    view, args, kwargs = resolve(urlparse(next)[2])
    kwargs['request'] = request
    try:
        view(*args, **kwargs)
    except Http404:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    return response
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do like this

```
def my_class(request, class_id):
    # this class_id is the class_id in url
    # do something;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using generic views or just views, you can do something like this:

```
class myView(View): # or UpdateView, CreateView, DeleteView
    template_name = 'mytemplate.html'
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        class_id = self.kwargs['class_id']

        # do something with your class_id

        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    # same with the post method.
```